# Next auth v4 Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames

Tags: next.js, next-auth, azure-ad-b2c

Need authorization using azure b2c

All settings from original documentation https://next-auth.js.org/providers/azure-ad-b2c

```
import AzureADB2CProvider from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad-b2c';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    AzureADB2CProvider({
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME,
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      primaryUserFlow: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW,
      authorization: { params: { scope: 'offline_access openid' } },
    }),
  ],
});
```

.env.local is already done with right data (as from guide), but have this error when trying to signin http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin:

```
stack: "Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: somename.onmicrosoft.com.b2clogin.com. is 
not in the cert's altnames: DNS:graph.windows.net, DNS:*.aadg.windows.net, DNS:*.aadkds.ppe.reporting.msidentity.com, DNS:*.aadkds.prd.reporting.msidentity
.com, DNS:*.accesscontrol.aadtst3.windows-int.net, DNS:*.accesscontrol.windows-ppe.net, DNS:*.accesscontrol.windows.net, DNS:*.adls.aadkds.ppe.reporting.ms
identity.com, DNS:*.adls.aadkds.prd.reporting.msidentity.com, DNS:*.adti.aadkds.ppe.reporting.msidentity.com, DNS:*.adti.aadkds.prd.reporting.msidentity.co
m, DNS:*.authapp.net, DNS:*.authorization.azure-ppe.net, DNS:*.authorization.azure.net, DNS:*.b2clogin.com, DNS:*.cpim.windows.net, DNS:*.d2k.aadkds.ppe.re
porting.msidentity.com, DNS:*.d2k.aadkds.prd.reporting.msidentity.com, DNS:*.fp.measure.office.com, DNS:*.gateway.windows.net, DNS:*.Identity.azure-int.net
, DNS:*.Identity.azure.net, DNS:*.login.live.com, DNS:*.login.microsoft.com, DNS:*.login.microsoftonline.com, DNS:*.login.windows-ppe.net, DNS:*.logincert.
microsoft.com, DNS:*.logincert.windows-ppe.net, DNS:*.microsoftaik-int.azure-int.net, DNS:*.microsoftaik.azure.net, DNS:*.pt.aadg.msidentity.com, DNS:*.r.l
ogin.microsoft.com, DNS:*.r.login.microsoftonline.com, DNS:*.r.prd.aadg.msidentity.com, DNS:*.windows-ppe.net, DNS:aadcdn.privatelink.msidentity.com, DNS:a
adcdnimages.privatelink.msidentity.com, DNS:aadg.windows.net, DNS:aadgcdn.windows-int.net, DNS:aadgcdn.windows.net, DNS:aadgv6.ppe.windows.net, DNS:aadgv6.
windows.net, DNS:accesscontrol.aadtst3.windows-int.net, DNS:account.live-int.com, DNS:account.live.com, DNS:api.login.live-int.com, DNS:api.login.microsoft
online.com, DNS:api.password.ccsctp.com, DNS:api.passwordreset.microsoftonline.com, DNS:autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com, DNS:becws.ccsctp.com, DNS:clien
tconfig.microsoftonline-p-int.net, DNS:clientconfig.microsoftonline-p.net, DNS:companymanager.ccsctp.com, DNS:companymanager.microsoftonline.com, DNS:cpim.
windows.net, DNS:device.login.microsoftonline.com, DNS:device.login.windows-ppe.net, DNS:directoryproxy.ppe.windows.net, DNS:directoryproxy.windows.net, DN
S:gatewayforking.windows.net, DNS:graph.ppe.windows.net, DNS:graphstore.windows.net, DNS:ipv6.login.live-int.com, DNS:login-us.microsoftonline.com, DNS:log
in.live-int.com, DNS:login.live.com, DNS:login.microsoft-ppe.com, DNS:login.microsoft.com, DNS:login.microsoftonline-int.com, DNS:login.microsoftonline-p.c
om, DNS:login.microsoftonline-pst.com, DNS:login.microsoftonline.com, DNS:login.passport-int.com, DNS:login.windows.net, DNS:logincert.microsoftonline-int.
com, DNS:logincert.microsoftonline.com, DNS:loginnet.passport-int.com, DNS:microsoftaik-int.azure-int.net, DNS:microsoftaik.azure.net, DNS:msnia.login.live
-int.com, DNS:msnialogin.passport-int.com, DNS:nexus.microsoftonline-p-int.com, DNS:nexus.microsoftonline-p.com, DNS:nexus.passport-int.com, DNS:pas.window
s-ppe.net, DNS:pas.windows.net, DNS:password.ccsctp.com, DNS:passwordreset.activedirectory.windowsazure.us, DNS:passwordreset.microsoftonline.com, DNS:ppe.
aadcdn.privatelink.msidentity.com, DNS:provisioning.microsoftonline.com, DNS:signup.live-int.com, DNS:signup.live.com, DNS:sts.windows.net, DNS:tools.login.live-int.com, DNS:xml.login.live-int.com, DNS:xml.login.live.com\n" +
      '    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)\n' +
      '    at Object.checkServerIdentity (node:tls:337:12)\n' +
      '    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1544:27)\n' +
      '    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)\n' +
      '    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:948:8)\n' +
      '    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:729:12)',
    name: 'Error'
  },
  providerId: 'azure-ad-b2c',
```

Does anybody know how to fix it? Google didn't help at all. Seems like azure works fine (can  signing from link) but it's not working with nextjs and next-auth

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error.
It was a problem with `AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME`, which should be `yourTenantName`, not `yourTenantName.onmicrosoft.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using `pg-pool` / `pg-adapter`.

Couldn't find any proper doc on how to set the hostname but eventually got it working through trial and error so sharing here:

```js
// in your ssl config, add the host from the certificate

poolConfig = {
  host: ...
  password: ...,
  ...
  ssl: {
    host: '<certificate-hostname>' // ! here
    ca: ...
    key: ...
    cert: ...
  }
}
const pool = new Pool(poolConfig);
...
```

Hope that helps :)